# Can the verb 'send' take a person as its object?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, appropriate

On Saturday morning, I was in the office working on my PC. At the time, a message popped up on GTalk, where the person had written "Send Martin" (who sits behind me) — my colleague wanted to talk with him, so told me to send him to his desk.

So my question is, is "send" appropriate to use for a person in this case?

Comment: Yes, just as troops are sent to war, you can send a colleague to the other side of the office.

Comment: okay but why downvote? I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted so I can't say for sure. There is a vote to close on this question based on it not being clear what you are asking.  If you restructure your question a little you may find that the person retracts their downvote.  However, I would advise showing that you have viewed the various definitions of [send](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/send?q=send).

Comment: now it is clear to you my question?

Comment: It was clear to me originally but yes, it is clearer now.  I would still add a dictionary reference that you think might be suitable so that it shows evidence of some research.

Comment: Thanks man. you can convert your comment into answer so I can accept it and also good for community too..

Comment: Say thank you to @anotherdave, and study where he made the corrections. It will help improve your English :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this definition from the [dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/send?q=send):

> order or instruct to go to a particular destination or in a particular direction:
>     *the BBC sent me to Washington to cover the trial*

So, yes, it perfectly acceptable to send people, animals or robots:

> The UK has sent another 1000 troops to support the efforts in Afghanistan.

or:

> I have sent the dog outside to do its business.

or, in your example:

> Could you send Martin to see me, please?